# Adding slideUp & slide down to mouseenter / remove and add / removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal type deal with `display: none;` using `removeClass` on it to make it appear.

I'd like to add a slideUp and slideDown function but haven't been able to get it to work.

Any ideas?

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown').mouseleave(function(e) {
    window.t = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hidden-dropdown').addClass("hide_k").slideUp('slow');
    }, 250)
  }).mouseenter(function(e) {
    if (window.t) {
      clearTimeout(window.t)
      window.t = undefined;
      $(".hidden-dropdown").removeClass("hide_k").slideDown('slow');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: You could use JQuery's animate function here. https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: do you have a specific example?

Comment: You could start with the css property: transform: translateY(-100%). then using the animate function bring the element up into view back to translateY(0px); I don't have a specific example.

Comment: You can't `slideUp` or `slideDown` after element is hidden, you could achieve this even without `addClass` and `removeClass`, just by using `$(".hidden-dropdown").slideDown('slow')` and `$('.hidden-dropdown').slideUp('slow')`